# Xcode Stuck Processing Files

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, cifilter

Xcode is stuck on processing files. When I comment this code it will complete it's processing, but when I uncomment it, it never completes it's processing.

Ps: I'm using this to fetch and set default filter parameter values.

```
let CICategoryBlur: [[[String: AnyObject]]] = [
    [["CIBoxBlur": nil], ["inputImage": nil], ["inputRadius": 10.0]],
    [["CIDiscBlur": nil], ["inputImage": nil], ["inputRadius": 8.0]],
    [["CIGaussianBlur": nil], ["inputImage": nil], ["inputRadius": 10.0]],
    [["CIMaskedVariableBlur": nil], ["inputImage": nil], ["inputMask": nil], ["inputRadius": 100.0]],
    [["CIMedianFilter": nil], ["inputImage": nil]],
    [["CIMotionBlur": nil], ["inputImage": nil], ["inputRadius": 20.0], ["inputAngle": 0.0]],
    [["CINoiseReduction": nil], ["inputImage": nil], ["inputNoiseLevel": 0.02], ["inputSharpness": 0.4]],
    [["CIZoomBlur": nil], ["inputImage": nil], ["inputCenter": CIVector(values: [150, 150], count: UInt(2))], ["inputAmount": 20.0]]]
```

I think `CIVector(values: [150, 150], count: UInt(2))` is causing the problem but I'm not 100% sure about this.

**OR**

Is it because of `[[[String: AnyObject]]]`, the way I am using it? If it is how would I use it correctly?

Comment: The problem is AnyObject is an optional. Try AnyObject?

Comment: Yes i figured out that it was an optional, but thanks any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Yes you were right about that is is to complex. What I did was to fix it: `[[String: AnyObject?]]` I added to the reduced array.

Answer (score 1):

XCode has had problems like this for a while now. The complexity of your array is too high, you should break it up into multiple expressions. Eventually I'd think Swift should be able to handle stuff like that.

Comment: I just figured out another thing. It actually isn't to complex. `CIVector(values: [150, 150], count: UInt(2))` should be `CIVector(values: [150, 150], count: 2)`